# Adding a Layer to a Scene does not work

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, subclass, layer, scene

I have been trying to get a layer into my scene. My scene is called "Survival". My layer is called "SSpriteLayer". The scene initializes, but the layer doesn't.

**SURVIVAL.H:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "SSpriteLayer.h"

@interface Survival : CCLayer {}
@end
```

**SURVIVAL.M:**

```
@implementation Survival

+(CCScene *) scene
{
   // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
   CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

   // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
   Survival *layer = [Survival node];
   SSpriteLayer *spriteLayer = [SSpriteLayer node];

   // add layer as a child to scene
   [scene addChild: layer];
   [scene addChild: spriteLayer];

   // return the scene
   return scene;
}

-(id) init
{
   if( (self=[super init]))        
       NSLog(@"SCENE HAS INIT");

   return self;
}

@end
```

**SSPRITELAYER.H:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface SSpriteLayer : CCLayer {

}

@end
```

**SSPRITELAYER.M:**

```
#import "SSpriteLayer.h"


@implementation SSpriteLayer

-(id) init
{
   if( (self=[super init]))         
       NSLog(@"SPRITELAYER HAS INIT");  

   return self;
}


@end
```

---

What I do not understand is why my layer isn't initizializing, and why I am not getting the message "SPRITELAYER HAS INIT" in the debug area.

Comment: What's the problem? Also, what do you mean by: *" I have imported SurvivalHudLayer.h"*? Can you post some code?

Comment: @sch
The problem is that my layer doesn't initialize, it dosne't appear, I never get the message "HUD LAYER HAS INIT". The code for the importing the lay into the game scene is in the question now.

Comment: And what is `Survival`, can you post the code for that? Also, does you code actually compile, or is it different from the code you posted here?

Comment: Well, survival is just the game scene. I have a couple of different gamemodes in my game, and this one is called survival

Comment: @sch I have reformatted the question, giving out more information. I have changes the name of the layer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  // add layer as a child to scene
  [self addChild: layer];
  [self addChild: SpriteLayer];
```

Change it And Try

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you call

```
[Survival scene];
```

not

```
[Survival node];
```

and post code with calling your scene here